# Matlab error for input

Tags: matlab

What does this error mean in matlab? When I run the function on command window using 2 input images (the images are in tif format, floating point,32 bit and  their size are (5165,11945,7)), matlab show me the following error message.

`Undefined function or method (name of input image) for input arguments of type double`.

Some people said that it is because of different woriking directory. But so far, I have only one working directory in matlab (`c:\User\user\Documents\MATLAB\`). All my images are in it. I can see them on matlab screen in the file list of current director icon. I'm really confused where this error comes from. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: can you show the command you used? you'd better describe your problem more clearly.

Comment: I would guess that in your function there is a comment line missing the `%` at the beginning of the line. Open the function in the editor, search the file for `name of input image` and put a `%` at the beginning of the line.

Comment: I wrote the following command on command window to run the function named D_old. The two variables in bracket are images used here as inputs in D_old function. 
D_old(rnf_4_a, tmp_4_a)
Then the error “Undefined function and method ‘tmp_4_a’ for inputs arguments of type ‘double’” appeared on command window. This tmp_4_a is an input image. So Is this problem with input image?

Comment: @H.Muster, I checked the function I wrote according to your suggestion. I didn't see any missing % at the beginning of the line. % is used to write description in function file, right? Then I checked carefully. So it seems not because of this.

Comment: Yes, your last comment suggested that I am wrong. Are ‘tmp_4_a’ variable names or file names? If the latter: are they full file names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Matlab uses parenthesis instead of square braces for vector/matrix indexing it cannot distinguish between variables and functions with the same name.  For example in Java if you have an array and function both named `foo`, you access values in the array with:

```
foo[index];
```

And you would call the function with:

```
foo(parameter);
```

However in matlab indexing into the vector `foo` and calling the function `foo` are both done using the same syntax:

```
foo(someValue);
```

Because of this confusion, Matlab first assumes that all calls are to variables. If a  variable with the specified name doesn't exist then it tries to find a function with the same name.

Your error:

> Undefined function or method **VariableName**  for input arguments
>   of type double.

Indicates that Matlab thinks you are trying to call a function named `VariableName`. This means two things:

1. There is **NOT** a variable named `VariableName`
2. There is **NOT** a function named `VariableName` on your matlab path.

To rectify this problem, first determine if you are trying to index into a variable or call a function. Then ensure that either that variable exists or that the function is on your path.

Comment: Thanks a lot Slayton. It was because I didn't convert the image file to variable in matlab.